# How to get the external url element using Cordova?

Tags: cordova

I have finished the app using Cordova web view, but the problem is how to get the external url elements using cordova app?

So, please give me a solution

Answer (score -1):

Just Install the plugin called [inappbrowser](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/10.x/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/) and add a class to anchor tags like

```
<a href="google.com" class="external-link">External Link</a>
```

And make sure you have JQuery library. Paste the code in js file at the bottom.

```
$(document).on('click','.external-link',function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   e.stopImmediatePropogation();
   var extLink = $(this).prop('href'); //get link of clicked anchor tag
   cordova.InAppBrowser.open(extLink , '_blank', 'location=yes'); //open it externally
});
```

Comment: No sir, i am not telling like this, i'am only getting and access external url elements and objects by using cordova
 for example if we using Google website running inappbrowser,and
 get a website elements dynamically

Comment: No that's not possible, It would be a security issue.  You can use HTML Parser libraries and get the element and its classes, texts and attributes for reading.